# How can I apply Texture on Cube using Three.js

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

```
    // Make a cube with Lambert material
    // ---------------------------------
    // Lower fragments can increase performance
    var cubeWidth = cubeSize,
        cubeHeight = cubeSize,
        cubeDepth = 10,
        cubeQuality = 1;
    // create the cube's material
    

var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
            {
                color: 0xb22222
            }
            );
    
// create a cube with sphere geometry and the meterial
```

---

```
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(
            cubeWidth, 
            cubeHeight, 
            cubeDepth,
            cubeQuality,
            cubeQuality,
            cubeQuality
            ),
        cubeMaterial);
```

lift the cube to half of the playing space height

```
cube.position.z = fieldDepth/2;
```

set the cube x position in the left of the play field

```
cube.position.x = -fieldWidth/3;
```

----------add the cube to the scene-------------------------

```
scene.add(cube);
```

---

I have tried ;

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var texture1 = texture.load('scripts/kan.png');
    
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(
            cubeWidth, 
            cubeHeight, 
            cubeDepth,
            cubeQuality,
            cubeQuality,
            cubeQuality
            ));
    
    
    var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
        {
             map: texture1
            //color: 0xb22222
        }
        );
    // create a cube with sphere geometry and the meterial
    
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( cube, cubeMaterial );
```

And this, but it didn't work

```
const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'kan.png' );
    
    var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
        {
            //color: 0xb22222
            map: texture
        }
        );
```

---

I am also getting the following error : THREE.Material: 'map' parameter is undefined

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue by modifying this live example? https://jsfiddle.net/r2vfupeo/

Comment: You're passing `cube`, that is `THREE.Mesh()` into the constructor of `mesh`, that is also `THREE.Mesh()`. `cube` has to be of `THREE.Geometry()`/`THREE.BufferGeometry()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.